# Pointers ! difference between two expressions

Tags: c++, pointers

I was wondering if anyone can tell me the difference between two expressions:
*(ptr+i) and *ptr+i
It is used in the code as follows:

```
char string[]="hello";
char  *ptr;
ptr=string;
for(int i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
{
cout<<*(ptr+i); //*ptr+i
}
```

Comment: [See `operator precedence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `*(ptr+i)` will print the character at offset `i` from memory location pointer by `ptr` AND `*ptr + i` will increment the value at memory location pointed by `ptr` by i. Besides that your for loop terminating condition is wrong. It should be `string[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: I still don't get it. Make it easier please !! @Arunmu

Comment: \ is not the same as /.

Comment: `*ptr+i` parses as `(*ptr) + i`, i.e. it dereferences `ptr`, then adds `i` to the result. On the other hand, `*(ptr + i)` adds `i` to `ptr`, then dereferences the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an array of 3 integers, with values 150, 200, and 250. In memory, this array would look like:

```
 +----------+----------+----------+---
 | 96000000 | c8000000 | fa000000 |...
 +----------+----------+----------+---
 | aka 150  | aka 200  | aka 250  |...
 +----------+----------+----------+---
 a          (a+1)      (a+2)
```

Now, you're not dealing with an array of integers here, but integers are somewhat easier to demonstrate.

Pointers and arrays are largely interchangeable in C/C++, so in the above example, think of `a` as a pointer. Already this means that `string` and `ptr` are essentially the same variable.

With that said, the difference between `*(pointer+i)` and `*pointer+1` is what the 1 is applied to. In the first case, it is the *pointer's address*. In the second case, it is the *value* the pointer points to. To continue with the above example:

```
int x = *a+1; // x is 151
int y = *(a+1); // y is 200
int z = *(a+1)+1; // z is 201
```